# Force Refresh Angular For Printing

Tags: angular, printing

I have an Angular page that is setup for the user to print. Then I also have a big button on the page that says "Print". What I want to do is when the user clicks the button, I want to hide that "Print" button, print the page, and then show the button again. By default this `ToggleForPrint` variable is `false`.

```
<ng-container *ngIf="!ToggleForPrint">
  <button (click)="Print()">Print</button>
</ng-container>

....

Print() {
  this.ToggleForPrint = true;
  window.print();
  this.ToggleForPrint = false;
}
```

However, this does not work. When the print screen comes up, the print button is still there. Somehow we need a refresh after the `this.ToggleForPrint = true;` line.

Answer (score 3):

I would not use angular to solve this problem and instead use css. You can create a `hide-on-print` class that you can apply to the button (or any element) to make it disappear when you print the page. Like so:

```css
@media print {
  .hide-on-print {
    visibility: hidden;
  }
}
```

and use it:

```html
<button class="hide-on-print" (click)="Print()">Print</button>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Print() {
  this.ToggleForPrint = true;
  window.print();
}

@HostListener('window:afterprint', ['$event'])
afterPrint() {
  this.ToggleForPrint = false;
}
```

This should get rid of your issue. If not, add a timeout :

```
Print() {
  this.ToggleForPrint = true;
  setTimeout(() => window.print());
}
```